# How do I get Azure Active Directory App Roles to show in Claims?

Tags: c#, .net, azure-active-directory, openid-connect, umbraco

I'm using Azure Active Directory to provide authentication to the Backoffice on my website running Umbraco version 11.0.

This is working nicely and I can log in but I want to improve the experience by using app roles within Azure to manage the user's group within Umbraco.

**My Azure setup**

I've created an App Registration within Azure with the following configuration:

- Added a Redirection URI:
- URI: https://localhost:44391/umbraco-signin-microsoft/
- Enabled `Access tokens (used for implicit flows)`
- Enabled `ID tokens (used for implicit and hybrid flows)`
- Supported account types: `Accounts in this organizational directory only (Example only - Single tenant)`
- Added App Roles

  - Administrator
  - Editor

[image]

In Enterprise Applications, I've also added the App Roles above to my users:

[image]

**My code**

Login Provider

```
namespace Example.Api.Features.Authentication.Extensions;

public static class UmbracoBuilderExtensions
{
    public static IUmbracoBuilder ConfigureAuthentication(this IUmbracoBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Services.ConfigureOptions<OpenIdConnectBackOfficeExternalLoginProviderOptions>();

        builder.AddBackOfficeExternalLogins(logins =>
        {
            const string schema = MicrosoftAccountDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                
            logins.AddBackOfficeLogin(
                backOfficeAuthenticationBuilder =>
                {
                    backOfficeAuthenticationBuilder.AddMicrosoftAccount(
                        // the scheme must be set with this method to work for the back office
                        backOfficeAuthenticationBuilder.SchemeForBackOffice(OpenIdConnectBackOfficeExternalLoginProviderOptions.SchemeName) ?? string.Empty,
                        options =>
                        {
                            //By default this is '/signin-microsoft' but it needs to be changed to this
                            options.CallbackPath = "/umbraco-signin-microsoft/";
                            //Obtained from the AZURE AD B2C WEB APP
                            options.ClientId = "CLIENT_ID";
                            //Obtained from the AZURE AD B2C WEB APP
                            options.ClientSecret = "CLIENT_SECRET";
                            options.TokenEndpoint = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/TENANT/oauth2/v2.0/token";
                            options.AuthorizationEndpoint = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/TENANT/oauth2/v2.0/authorize";
                        });
                });
        });

        return builder;
    }
}
```

Auto-linking accounts

```
namespace Example.Api.Features.Configuration;

public class OpenIdConnectBackOfficeExternalLoginProviderOptions : IConfigureNamedOptions<BackOfficeExternalLoginProviderOptions>
{
    public const string SchemeName = "OpenIdConnect";

    public void Configure(string name, BackOfficeExternalLoginProviderOptions options)
    {
        if (name != "Umbraco." + SchemeName)
        {
            return;
        }

        Configure(options);
    }

    public void Configure(BackOfficeExternalLoginProviderOptions options)
    {
        options.AutoLinkOptions = new ExternalSignInAutoLinkOptions(
            // must be true for auto-linking to be enabled
            autoLinkExternalAccount: true,

            // Optionally specify default user group, else
            // assign in the OnAutoLinking callback
            // (default is editor)
            defaultUserGroups: new[] { Constants.Security.EditorGroupAlias },

            // Optionally you can disable the ability to link/unlink
            // manually from within the back office. Set this to false
            // if you don't want the user to unlink from this external
            // provider.
            allowManualLinking: false
        )
        {
            // Optional callback
            OnAutoLinking = (autoLinkUser, loginInfo) =>
            {
                // You can customize the user before it's linked.
                // i.e. Modify the user's groups based on the Claims returned
                // in the externalLogin info

                autoLinkUser.IsApproved = true;
            },
            OnExternalLogin = (user, loginInfo) =>
            {
                // You can customize the user before it's saved whenever they have
                // logged in with the external provider.
                // i.e. Sync the user's name based on the Claims returned
                // in the externalLogin info

                return true; //returns a boolean indicating if sign in should continue or not.
            }
        };

        // Optionally you can disable the ability for users
        // to login with a username/password. If this is set
        // to true, it will disable username/password login
        // even if there are other external login providers installed.
        options.DenyLocalLogin = true;

        // Optionally choose to automatically redirect to the
        // external login provider so the user doesn't have
        // to click the login button. This is
        options.AutoRedirectLoginToExternalProvider = true;
    }
}
```

In this file, I'd ideally do as the comment says and `i.e. Modify the user's groups based on the Claims returned in the externalLogin info`.

Also registered in my Startup file

```
services.AddUmbraco(_env, _config)
            .AddBackOffice()
            .AddWebsite()
            .AddComposers()
            .ConfigureAuthentication()
            .Build();
```

I've attempted to give the following permissions to the application, with no luck:

[image]

Current state of play is that I can login just fine but if I debug  `externalInfo`, there's nothing in there about the users having either the `Administrator` or `Editor` App Role as configured above.

My gut feeling is that I'm missing something with the Azure Active Directory setup but I've tried a few different configurations and can't seem to get the App Roles to come back.

Thanks,

Ben

**EDIT - 15.02.2023:**

I can see that the roles come back when I hit the `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token` endpoint using `client_credentials` as the `grant_type`. It looks like the .NET application using `authorization_code` instead. I've decoded the token retrieved from this and it doesn't contain the roles.

I wonder if there's some kind of configuration on the .NET application that allows me to add the roles.

Comment: Have you granted **admin consent** to the `App roles` in your Azure AD application?

Comment: I think so though I couldn't find anything specifically lablelled `App roles`. I've updated my question.

Comment: When you created the app roles, is the member type Users/Groups or Both?

Comment: Did you extract the received token from the network tab of the interactive web logon and checked its content on https://jwt.ms or https://jwt.io if it contains the roles?

Comment: @Oliver The member type for the roles is set to `User/Group + Applications`. I checked the token coming back and it doesn't contain roles. Though if I hit the token endpoint manually using the `client_credentials` `grant_type`, it does contain the roles. The code uses `authorisation_code` instead which doesn't contain the roles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this, I ended up swapping out the `AddMicrosoftAccount` `AuthenticationBuilder` in favour of `AddOpenIdConnect`. This appears to respect the claims in the tokens.

This is the code I am now using in the `ConfigureAuthentication` method.

```
public static IUmbracoBuilder ConfigureAuthentication(this IUmbracoBuilder builder)
{
    // Register OpenIdConnectBackOfficeExternalLoginProviderOptions here rather than require it in startup
    builder.Services.ConfigureOptions<OpenIdConnectBackOfficeExternalLoginProviderOptions>();

    builder.AddBackOfficeExternalLogins(logins =>
    {
        logins.AddBackOfficeLogin(
            backOfficeAuthenticationBuilder =>
            {
                backOfficeAuthenticationBuilder.AddOpenIdConnect(
                    // The scheme must be set with this method to work for the back office
                    backOfficeAuthenticationBuilder.SchemeForBackOffice(OpenIdConnectBackOfficeExternalLoginProviderOptions.SchemeName),
                    options =>
                    {
                        options.CallbackPath = "/umbraco-signin-microsoft/";
                        // use cookies
                        options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                        // pass configured options along
                        options.Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/v2.0";
                        options.ClientId = "{clientId}";
                        options.ClientSecret = "{clientSecret}";
                        // Use the authorization code flow
                        options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;
                        options.AuthenticationMethod = OpenIdConnectRedirectBehavior.RedirectGet;
                        // map claims
                        options.TokenValidationParameters.NameClaimType = "name";
                        options.TokenValidationParameters.RoleClaimType = "role";

                        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;
                        options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
                        options.SaveTokens = true;
                        options.UsePkce = true;
                        
                        options.Scope.Add("email");
                    });
            });
    });
    return builder;
}
```

Comment: Just to confirm - you were able to get the roles using your original setup? And didn't have to use client credentials?

Answer (score 5):

To get **App Roles** in token claims, you can use client credentials flow to generate access tokens by granting admin consent.

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment via Postman and got the below results:***

I registered one Azure AD **web** application and created **App roles** like below:

[image]

Now I assigned these **App roles** to users under it's Enterprise application like below:

[image]

Add these **App roles** in API permissions of application like below:

[image]

You can see **App roles** under **`Application`** permissions like below:

[image]

Make sure to grant **admin consent** to above permissions like this:

[image]

While generating access token, scope should be your **Application ID URI** ending with `/.default`

[image]

Now, I generated **access token** using client credentials flow via Postman with below parameters:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id: <appID>
grant_type:client_credentials
scope: api://<appID>/.default
client_secret: secret
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I decoded the above token in [jwt.ms](https://jwt.ms/), I got **App roles** in **`roles`** claim successfully like below:

[image]

> Note that App roles are **Application** permissions that will work only with flows like client credentials which do not involve user interaction.

So, if you use **delegated** flows like authorization code flow, username password flow, etc..., you won't get **App roles** in token claims.

**UPDATE:**

You can use below **c# code** in getting access token from client credentials flow like this:

```cs
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;

var clientID = "bbb739ad-98a4-4566-8408-dxxxxxxxx3b";
var clientSecret = "K.k8Q~hwtxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxU";
var tenantID = "fb134080-e4d2-45f4-9562-xxxxxx";
var authority = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantID}";
var clientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientID)
  .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
  .WithAuthority(authority)
  .Build();
var scopes = new string[] { "api://bbb739ad-98a4-4566-8408-xxxxxx/.default" };
var authenticationResult = await clientApplication.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes)
  .ExecuteAsync()
  .ConfigureAwait(false);
var accesstoken = authenticationResult.AccessToken;
Console.WriteLine(accesstoken);
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I decoded the above token, it has **`roles`** claim with **App roles** like below:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Unfortunately, while this works and is great to see that roles are coming back - the token retrieved by ASP.NET doesn't contain them. This despite using the same `TokenEndpoint` as works in Postman. I'm guessing the problem is with the ASP implementation, rather than Azure, at this point.

Comment: Have you changed the `grant_type` to **client_credentials** and `scope` parameters while generating the token in ASP.NET?

Comment: It still uses `authorization_code` as the `grant_type`. I'm not sure how/if I can change these with the current ASP.NET setup.